# Is there a way to tell JSTL ${} to escape html globally, instead of on each use

Tags: java, escaping, jstl

We have an app which uses JSTL syntax in many places (e.g. ${thisVar}, and we are wondering if there is a flag to globally escape HTML in a similar way that the fn:escape... attribute does:

`${fn:escapeXml(myName)}`

We don't want to have to go through our entire application and change all the variables. Also, simple ${} is much easier to type.

Comment: create your own tag or function

Comment: I think `<c:out value="${myName}"/>` exists for that purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate, yes, but no answer yet given even on the linked question. Just lots of commentary. And NO, using c:out is not an answer because I am trying to avoid changing the ${} syntax.